# Django admin: __str__ returned non-string (type long) on adding a user

Tags: python, django

In my django app when i want to add a user in my app.it throws a error

```
__str__ returned non-string (type long)
```

why this error is occurred.
i also try unicode instead of str but error remain same.

my models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    c_id=models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
    u_id=models.OneToOneField(Consultants)
    comany_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    comany_email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.c_id)
```

This error is appearing at the time of adding company

exception location

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 94
```

Comment: show `__str__` method of this model, please

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are returning a long integer, like for example, the model `self.id`. In that case, you need to format it:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.id)
```

Or

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{}'.format(self.id)
```

Unicode is usually preferred, django takes care of implementing `__str__`. But you could implement `__str__` in a similar way.

Comment: Which python version are you using ? Are you getting the very same error ?

Comment: python version 2.7

Comment: Your code seems correct. Do you have any other model that could be affected ? Maybe `Consultants` ?